# When I use an IQueryable function, it significantly increase the time of the query

Tags: c#, performance, linq, oracle, entity-framework

How come when I do the following:

```
var query = from a in OBJ where a.ID == ID select c;
```

It does it <1second, but once I add the IQueryable function, it increases it to ~3seconds?

```
var query = (from a in OBJ where a.ID == ID select c).SingleOrDefault();
```

The same happens when I use FirstOrDefault().

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This:

```
var query = from a in OBJ where a.ID == ID select c;
```

... just *represents* the query. It doesn't *execute* it at all. It should be *blazingly* quick - not just "less than a second" but "almost immeasurably fast."

This:

```
var query = (from a in OBJ where a.ID == ID select c).SingleOrDefault();
```

... gets *actual data* which means it has to execute the query.

In general, LINQ uses *deferred execution* where possible. This is just one example. Search for LINQ deferred execution and you'll get *loads* of hits of articles to read. Dive into whichever one suits your reading style best :)

Comment: Right now I have <20 entries in the database, but it takes ~3 seconds to run. Is there a faster way to retrieve the data? I don't want to have to have to click on something in the application and wait ~3 seconds every time. I'm using a TPT hierarchy with inheritance with Oracle database.

Comment: @Bob.: I suspect you'll find it takes ~3 seconds if you're using the debugger and this is the very first query you're running. Subsequent queries should be much faster, and I'd expect that it wouldn't take that long when not running in the debugger, too. I suspect that a lot of that time is actually loading and JITting a bunch of stuff.

Comment: I tried it with and without the IQueryable, and this is what I get overall in milliseconds (First call, second call, third call). With IQueryable function #1 - 4930, 2584, 2467 #2 - 4988, 2445, 2478 #3 - 4618, 2823, 2449 Without IQueryale function #1 - 2355, 83, 62

Comment: @Bob.: What *exactly* do you mean by "with and without the IQueryable"? Because you're already *using* an `IQueryable` function (Where) in your code. Do you understand my answer? Your code which doesn't execute SingleOrDefault *isn't executing a query*. There's no point in comparing it with a query whic hactually does work.

Comment: I'm surprised at it taking 2.5 seconds to do work though. Is that still in the debugger? Where's the database? Have you profiled anything at all to work out where the time is going?

Comment: What I mean is comparing when I use SingleOrDefault() or whether I just represent the query. `var query = (from a in OBJ where a.ID == ID select c).SingleOrDefault();` versus `var query = from a in OBJ where a.ID == ID select c`

Comment: @Bob.: Yes, but what's the point of making that comparison? Would you usually compare creating an instance of `WebClient` with calling `WebClient.DownloadString`? Because that's exactly the sort of comparison you're making. (I'm really astonished at it taking 62ms to construct the query, too... again, is this running in a debugger?)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13238/discussion-between-bob-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong with the entity container? Is it possible that using the same container makes it cache more data every time, thus slowing down the execution time? As well, what is the most efficient way to query the database?

Comment: I found out that it wasn't the query execution that was causing the problem, it was the combination of the data retrieval and the query execution, it would have to go to the database every time whenever it executed the query, I changed it so I have a local object so it reduced the number of database retrievals from 10+ to 1 ( plus manual user refresh numbers).